# Sitecore Commerce Engine 403 forbidden error

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-engine

I am trying to debug a method from postman but I am getting this error

```
CommerceController.OnActionExecuting.Forbidden: User not allowed for action /extops/Synchronize
```

[image: error]

I am connected with the Sitecore/Admin user in the postman. I have also added the roles to the Sitecore/Admin account

```
sitecore\Commerce Administrator
sitecore\Commerce Business User
```

But I am keep getting the **403 forbidden error**.

Is there a way I can bypass the authentication?

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Look for **Sitecore.Commerce.Core.ControllerMethodRolesPolicy**.
It maps a Regular Expression to Authorized Roles.
In your case you need to add an entry for /extops/ and match it with whatever roles you want to Authorize.

If you are on 9.x then you'll find this policy under wwwroot\data\Environments\Core.ControllerMethodRoles.PolicySet-1.0.0.json

If you are on 10.x then you'll find it in Global.json